# Perl Modules - Sharing Database Connection

Tags: perl, perl-module, dbi

Can someone give me some direction on the best way to do when sharing a $dbh variable between "objects" in different .pm files.

For instance, my main module say Foo.pm has a new constructor, etc and I could give it a dbh or create a dbh and then share it by passing it as a parameter to the new constructor for Bar.pm, and then re-assigning inside Bar->new, but that seems like I'm doing a lot of work managing this variable.

Is this a simple, yet elegant way to do this? I've researched Exporter and a few other examples, but none seem to be straight forward.

Thanks!

Comment: Redesign your modules. You should have only *one* that writes to the database.

Comment: Consider DBIx::Connector.  Your main application can instantiate a connector object, and may provide it to the classes the app uses.  Connector objects can share a connection, or spin up a new one if the existing one dies.  This is one of the ways I deal with database interaction in full Mojolicious apps.

Comment: Try the Singleton pattern. You can write your own or try a Singleton base class from CPAN.

Comment: @Borodin, you're right, and that module is called `DBI`. If that's not the one you was referring to, then your statement is too strong to be true. Having a layer between DB and your business logic is a good practice in some cases (and then you better have *one* such layer indeed), but not in all cases and not even in the majority of cases, I'd say. *There's more than one way to do it*, you know.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that what you actually want is to take the control over $dbh creation out of the code that works with it. Most trivial way is, well,

```
my $dbh;
sub get_dbh {
    if ( $dbh is bad ) {
       reconnect or whatever
    }

    return $dbh || die;
}
```

And then in your code access it like

```
get_dbh()->do("your sql");
```

You could put that `get_dbh()` function to a separate module and call it from anywhere in your project - as usual with perl, it will be included only once and its local static variable $dbh will exist in only one copy within the perl process.

There are many possible ways to achieve that, writing a function like described above (and maybe passing a reference to that function instead of passing the $dbh) is one. There are plenty of others, depending on your design and personal taste - a singleton class, a variable tied to the function described above, or even a class that imitates DBI... That's up to you, but that should be *one* piece of code, spreading this logic all over your project is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.0801/lib/Moose.pm) to build your object, you could encapsulate your database handle in a [role](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) and require it into classes that need the database access.